# jQuery: css margin based on the amount of elements in container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple collage creator using jquery.

what I need to do is to have a margin of 1% between each element (collage).

But at the same time I need the collages to have 0 margin from their container.

I hope that makes sense.

I've created this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sxhf34on/) so you know what I mean.

when you run the code, just click on the button 4 times and you should see the collages being created inside the container perfectly fine BUT there is a margin between their container and its children elements which is not wanted.

Is there any way to sort this issue out?

This is my code:

```
$('#colBtn').live('click', function(){

    $('.lable').show();
    $('#reset').show();
    $('#fileField').show();
    $('#sbs').show();
    var width = $('#width').val();
    var height = $('#height').val();

    $('#main').append('<div class="droppable" style="width:'+width+';height:'+height+';overflow: hidden;  position:relative;float:left; margin:1%;"></div>');


    $('#layout').text($('#main').html());
    return false;
});
```

[image]

Comment: If there's a `margin` inside of the container, then the margin is on the child element, not on the container itself. `Padding` is what affects the inside of a container.

Comment: @GavinThomas, I don't have any padding in the container. I only have margin on the children.

Comment: You would need to ascertain the number of elements on each wrapped row then remove the margin-right from the last one one *on each row*.

Comment: @Paulie_D, what happens to the margins on the top and the margin of the left of first element of each row? also, I don't have any wrapper for each row!

Comment: Good to see a good quality question - demonstration of what's desired as well as what you've tried thus far. Nice.

Comment: If you have 2 items per row you can use css property `:nth-child(odd/even){}`. and adjust the margin

Comment: Same issue....you aren't using rows so determining where each element is in the virtual rows is the issue. It might be simpler just to use rows...

Comment: @FaheemAlam, no i might have 4 or 6 or 3 etc etc..... its totally dynamic. that's why there are two input fields to choose the width and height.

Comment: @Paulie_D, can you please let me know what you mean by rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a negative margin.

put another div in your #main div and give it a negative margin.

```
margin: 0 -1%
```

This will make it as if it had no margin since you have

```
overflow: hidden
```

set to your main container.

Something like this: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxhf34on/4/)

Hope this gets you closer to your goal ;)

Comment: Ah I see you are not wrapping them into rows.

Comment: @ŽanMarolt, no... main reason being that I cannot warp them in a row because users might want to change the width and height of each collage!

Comment: Sorry but this is far from what I'm trying to do! The top margin of the first and second elements is even bigger than my own example.

Comment: You will have to play with the #wrapper's width and calculate it on your own but should be as simple as getting #main container's width and the adding 2*1% of the #main container's width.

Comment: Even though this solution is a bit "hacky", but its the closest solution. However, top margin is always set at 1% even if I change the height of the #wrapper to 102% or 105% etc... do you know why?

Comment: I just added a margin-top:-1%; to it and worked fine. cheers for the solution.

Comment: It seems "hacky" but is totally legit :). You will also need to increase height then. Because now it is set to 100% so it will not span through whole parent element since we have -1% margin on the top, which means it will move up 1% this means only 99% of the height will be visible. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

By the above given figure. The main issue seems like figuring out which is the first item and which is the last item of a row. having dynamic number of items in a row.

I just figure out the first item and last item you can use it to adjust margin.

```
function fix(){
var $item = $('.droppable');
var parentWidth = $item.parent().width();
var itemWidth = $item.outerWidth(true);
var itemInLine = Math.floor(parentWidth/itemWidth);
var totalItems = $item.length;
var rows = totalItems / itemInLine;

var lastItem = 0;
var firstItem = 1;
    for(var i = 1; i< rows + 1; i++){
    lastItem = i * itemInLine;
    $('.droppable:nth-child('+ lastItem +')').css({'margin-top':'0px','margin-right':'0px'});
    firstItem = (i * itemInLine) - itemInLine + 1;
    $('.droppable:nth-child('+ firstItem +')').css({'margin-top':'0px'});
    }
}
```